# Select only image in layer around selection

Tags: gimp, mac

[image]

Here is my current situation. I am trying to select the selection inside via CMD+SHIFT+L so I can move the gold coins around a bit. But I don't seem to be able to do so. Select -> Float seems not select it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ctrl-Shift-L` would indeed work on other systems.

Alternatively, you can use `Ctrl-X`+`Ctrl-V` to detach the area from the layer, move it around with the Move tool, and then anchor it back with `Ctrl-H`.